# Install Microsoft Self-Extracting EXE via Remote Powershell

Tags: wcf, powershell, appfabric, windows-server-2012, self-extracting

I'm attempting to [remote install AppFabric 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh351353.aspx) on a **Windows Server 2012 R2** machine for enabling [WCF auto-start features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx). My approach is to [copy the self-extraction package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115) (*WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe*) to the target machine and subsequently fire off `setup.exe /i` as stated in the [AppFabric automated installation guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh351353.aspx) to install all features.

The issue is that the self-extraction step is not enabling me to specify an output path (*`& WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe /extract:"c:\temp"` doesn't work*), so it just quits after copying all the extracted files to a GUID folder on the disk containing the most free space. The temp folder is then removed after it is extracted.

Do I have to copy the extracted files/folders myself (*shown below*) and then run `setup.exe`? Ideally I could just keep the self-extraction package (*32MB EXE*) intact and deploy it as a single step. It's looking as though the self-extraction that I downloaded is not meant as a re-distribution means - only as web delivery of the installer. I must have to copy the raw 90MB extracted installer files around.

#### Self-Extraction Package Contents (*WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe*)

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions - or improvement ideas?

#### Status Update

I ended up just copying the raw files (*90MB*) over and running `setup.exe /i /gac` via powershell to install all the AppFabric features. I'm just struggling with the proper re-distribution mechanism for Microsoft self-extracting packages.